# Spring-Boot Thymeleaf Binding Enum at hidden field

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, spring-boot, enums, thymeleaf

I would like to bind an enum at a hidden field to keep the information when submitting the form. Somehow the field of enum is null then.

My Object looks like:

```
public class Check {
    @NotNull        private String name;
    @NotNull        private CheckType type; // ENUM with GETTER & SETTER

    // BESIDE NORMAL GETTER & SETTER ANOTHER TRY ...
    public String getTypeName() {
        return type == null ? null : type.name();
    }

    public void setTypeName(String name) {
        type = CheckType.valueOf(name);
    }

    ...
}
```

In my Thymeleaf-Template I am iterating through the Objects and want to hold the enum:

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{checks[__${checkStat.index}__].type}" />       

<!-- ALSO TRIED ... -->
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{checks[__${checkStat.index}__].typeName}" />
```

After sending Form, type is null. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have the issue but was not viewable in my question. The enum mapping works, but what I also have in my class is something like:

```
public Integer getSpecialValue() {
    if (type == SOMETHING) {
        return rareEventThreshold;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}

// EQUALS TO SETTER
```

In fact I cant trust in which order the Getter & Setter are called, so that is not a good idea. I will now use a DTO Object with "normal" Getter & Setter without any logic.